# Netty Channel occurs channelOpen, not run channelBound/channelConnected/

Tags: netty

Initially, everything is normal. Channel always run `channelOpen`, `channelConnected` and `channelClosed`. But after some time ( 1 hour, 2 hours, etc.) , it ​​only runs `channelOpen`, without run the event `channelBound`, `channelConnected`. Can you help me explain?
Here are my code:

```
package net;
import main.Const;
import main.Global;
import main.PlayerContext;
import log.Log;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffer;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.*;

public class ChannelHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

    @Override
    public void channelOpen(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e){
        try{   
            super.channelOpen(ctx, e);
            Channel channel = ctx.getChannel(); 
            Server.getInstance().addChannel(channel);
            channel.setAttachment(new PlayerContext(channel));
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.write(this.getClass().getName()+"-channelOpen-Exception: "+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e){        
        try{            
            Channel channel = ctx.getChannel(); 
            PlayerContext playerContext = (PlayerContext)(channel.getAttachment());
            playerContext.setChannelState(Const.CHANNEL_CONNECTED);
super.channelConnected(ctx, e);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.write(this.getClass().getName()+"-channelConnected-Exception: "+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e){        
    try{ 
        Channel channel = e.getChannel(); 
        PlayerContext playerContext = (PlayerContext)(channel.getAttachment());
        if(playerContext != null){
            playerContext.setChannelState(Const.CHANNEL_CLOSE);
        }else{
            e.getChannel().close();
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Log.write(this.getClass().getName()+"-exceptionCaught-Exception: "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}



@Override
public void channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e){
    int k = 0;
    try{
        k++;
        Channel channel = ctx.getChannel();  
        k++;
        PlayerContext playerContext = (PlayerContext)(channel.getAttachment());
        k++;
        if(playerContext != null){
            playerContext.setChannelState(Const.CHANNEL_CLOSE);
        }else{
            ctx.getChannel().close();
        }
        Log.write(this.getClass().getName()+"-channelDisconnected: "+ channel.getRemoteAddress());
        super.channelDisconnected(ctx, e);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Log.write(this.getClass().getName()+"-channelDisconnected-Exception: "+k+"-"+ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void channelClosed(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e){        
    int k = 0;
    try{
        k++;
        Channel channel = ctx.getChannel();  

        Log.write(this.getClass().getName()+"-channelClosed: "+ channel.getRemoteAddress());
        super.channelClosed(ctx, e);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Log.write(this.getClass().getName()+"-channelClosed-Exception: "+k+"-"+ex.getMessage());
    }
}

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e){  
        byte[] bytes = null;

        try{         
            ChannelBuffer buffer=(ChannelBuffer)e.getMessage();

            int size=buffer.readableBytes();

            bytes = new byte[size];

            buffer.readBytes(bytes, 0, size);

            buffer.clear();

            Channel channel = ctx.getChannel();

            if(channel != null){

                PlayerContext playerContext = (PlayerContext)(channel.getAttachment());
                if(playerContext != null){
                    playerContext.clientMessage(bytes); 
                }else{
                    channel.close();
                }
            }else{
                Log.write(this.getClass().getName()+"-messageReceived: channel = null");
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){

            Log.write(this.getClass().getName()+"-messageReceived-Exception: "+ex.getMessage());
        }        
    } 
}
```

Comment: Maybe attach a profiler and check if the threads are blocked ?

Comment: I checked the log. I find error: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink
WARNING: Failed to accept a connection.
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)... I think that's the reason why the program can not run on channelConnect . But I do not know why so?

Comment: You may need to higher the ulimit for the user that run the program. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/

Comment: Thanks for your help . But I checked with 2-5 users, the error still appear. 
I'm still looking for situations to which the error occurred. If you know , I hope you help. Thank you!